Movie where main character is searching for the philosopher's stone, finds it underwater
The main male character (a grandfather) has the map for finding the fabled 'Philosopher's Stone'. He takes his daughter with him, tells her about the story and starts to dig here and there in the city in order to find the stone.
They end up breaking into a hypermarket and dig a big hole there, steal a scuba-diving costume for the grandpa. He jumps into the water, finds the "stone" and then he dies, while the cops come into the hypermarket and find his daughter.

Approximative year of release ? Language ? Country ? Horror movie ? I just saw that "As box, so below" is a little about that stone but it's an horror movie.

i don't know the year of release, the language used is english, not a horror movie, rather a drama mixed with adventure with a very known actor as the main character. no, not As above so below

Sounds like King of California, movie from 2007 with  Michael Douglas in leading role.

At the age of sixteen, Miranda (Evan Rachel Wood) has already had her
  share of disappointments. Abandoned by her mother, she's dropped out
  of school and has been supporting herself working at McDonald's while
  her father Charlie (Michael Douglas) is in a mental institution.
When Charlie is released and sent back to their home, Miranda finds
  the relatively peaceful existence she's built for herself completely
  disrupted. Charlie has become obsessed with the notion that the
  long-lost treasure of Spanish explorer Father Juan Florismarte Garces
  is buried somewhere near their suburban California housing unit.
Armed with a metal detector and a stack of treasure-hunting books,
  Charlie soon finds reason to believe that the gold is buried
  underneath the local Costco, and encourages Miranda to get a job there
  so that they can plan a way to excavate after hours.
Initially skeptical, Miranda soon finds herself joining in Charlie's
  questionable antics in an effort to give him one last shot at
  accomplishing his dreams in this darkly funny, exciting, and
  surprisingly hopeful take on the modern family and the American dream.

Here you can see the ending of movie.
